# AVD Missing Google Play Services

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-virtual-device

Though I am running 4.2.2 Android emulator I keep getting the error -

```
This app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your tablet.
```

Here is my `AVD` configuration.
[image]

I tried to `Get Google Play services` from the emulator but it keeps prompting the same dialog.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an AVD with a Target Name containing "Google APIs", not "Android". That, in turn, requires that you download the right emulator images from the SDK Manager, ones that have "Google APIs":

[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: There is no such an option.

Comment: @levi: See the updated answer with the SDK Manager screenshot. In my case, I need to update my images, as new versions have come out since I last updated.

Comment: After installing it I was able to see Google APIs in title. Now I'll try to run on it. (You know it will take a century)...